# I want to add product inside the cart

Tags: php, codeigniter, reference, codeigniter-2

In the below code I am able to create session and add first item in array.
But I am not able to append the array in it.
I am new to codigniter

```
   function guestcart($pID){

        $session = $this->session->userdata('guest');
        if(!empty($session)){  
            $addprod = $data;
            $addprod= array($pID);
            array_push($addprod,$data);

            echo 'Session Exist';
        } 
        else {     

    //set the session data    
        $data = array("guest",$pID);

    $session = $this->session->set_userdata('guest',$data);

    echo 'Session created';
}
```

}

Comment: where does the `$data` var get set and what does it contain? also in the exists bit `$addprod = array($pID);` will overwrite the `$data` var that is done just before it `$addprod = $data;`, in all honesty this would never work how you expect it to!

Comment: There is a shopping cart library in codeigniter: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/cart.html